# Get function tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I use tkinter on python 2.7. My problem is that I don't succeed in getting the variable entered into the entry_number; the function is called, but it didn't print anything.

How can I know if the checkbox is checked or not?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Label, Entry, Button

def call():
    print (e)

root = Tk()
var1 = IntVar()
c=Checkbutton(root, text="Bou ", variable=var1).grid(row=4, column=1)
text = StringVar(root)

button = Button(root, text='call', 
            command=call)
entry_number = Entry(root)
button.grid(column=8, row=20)
entry_number.grid(column=6,row=4)

e = entry_number.get()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ```from tkinter import *```
```from tkinter import Tk, StringVar, Label, Entry, Button``` not sure why you import it twice

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you define `e` immediately when you are creating the UI. At this point, the entry is still empty, so all that is printed when you press the button is an empty string.

Instead, put the definition of `e` inside the function, so it is updated each time you click:

```
def call():
    e = entry_number.get()
    print (e)
```